# Export different subsets of data.tables to each node in a cluster

Tags: r, parallel-processing, snow

I am writing a function that processes several very large data.tables and I want to parallelize this function on a Windows machine.

I could do this with the `snow` package using `clusterExport` to create a copy of each of the data.tables for each node in the cluster. However this does not work because it uses too much memory.

I want to fix this by exporting a different subset of the data.tables to each node, however, I can't see how to do this in the snow package.

Here is a toy example of code that works but is memory inefficient:

```
library(snow)
dd <- data.frame(a = rep(1:5, each = 2), b = 11:20)
cl <- makeCluster(2, type = "SOCK")
clusterExport(cl = cl, "dd")
clusterApply(cl, x = c(2,7),  function(thresh) colMeans(dd[dd$a < thresh,]))
stopCluster(cl)
```

Here is an example of code that does not work but explains how we would like to distribute subsets of `dd` to the nodes:

```
library(snow)
dd <- data.frame(a = rep(1:5, each = 2), b = 11:20)
cl <- makeCluster(2, type = "SOCK")

dd_exports <- lapply(c(2,7), function(thresh) dd[dd$a < thresh])
#Now we export the ith element of dd_exports to the ith node:
clusterExport(cl = cl, dd_exports) 
clusterApply(cl, x = c(2,7),  function(x) colMeans(dd))
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Please provide some code you tried with some data.

Comment: @f-privé I have added some code in an attempt to better explain the question.

Comment: Is your data composed of numeric data only? Is the computation that you need to do still much more demanding that the subsetting itself?

Comment: @f-privé My data is not numeric only; it is numeric, POSIXct and categorical. The computation is orders of magnitude more demanding than the subsetting.

Comment: So, I think the best would be to store each subset of the data.table in an RDS file. Then, each core read one file and do the computation on this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `cl` is a list, simply subset it during the `clusterExport` call:

```
library(data.table)
library(parallel)

dt <- data.table(a = rep(1:5, each = 2), b = 11:20)
cl <- makeCluster(2)
idx <- c(2, 7)

for (i in seq_along(cl)) {
  dt2 <- dt[a < idx[i]]
  clusterExport(cl[i], "dt2")
}
rm(dt2)
clusterEvalQ(cl, colMeans(dt2))
#> [[1]]
#>    a    b 
#>  1.0 11.5 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    a    b 
#>  3.0 15.5
```